# Appeal for undelete of a question

Tags: support

I would like to appeal for an undelete, since this question is puzzling me, and I would really like an answer!! I'll add a bounty if I have to:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79245/the-concept-of-a-user-vs-player?noredirect=1#comment141174_79245

Absolutely no effort was made to address my additional points in the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was automatically deleted after being closed for a set period of time. You could try asking the question again, with any attempts you've tried to solve the problem included in your question. Whatever you can include to narrow the scope would be good, since the question was closed as too broad.

I'm not saying the new question won't be closed as well. Just try to make sure it fits within the guidelines defined in the [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks, [I'll try that](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80436/user-vs-player-model).